# How to display: "Error: no connection" in php when there's no internet connection?

Tags: php, android, mysql, post, wifi

So I'm working on a login/register system with php which I can use for my Android app (working with Android Studio 2.3.1).

I can already register via my phone. But I found out that if I turn off the wifi and my data and I try to register an empty message gets displayed. I would like to fill this empty message with the text: "Error: no connection" but I really don't know how.

My code is:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
$hostname = "hostname";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";  

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);  

if (!$conn)
{ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  } 

mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn); 

$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$repeatpassword = $_POST["repeatpassword"]; 

if($name == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == ''){
echo 'Please fill in the missing fields';
}else{ 

$checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
username='$username'");
$checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$testusername = mysql_fetch_array($checkusername);
$testemail = mysql_fetch_array($checkemail);

if($testemail) {
echo 'Email is already used';
}else {   

if ($testusername){
echo 'Username already exists';
} else{ 

if ($_POST["password"] <> $_POST["repeatpassword"]) {
echo 'Passwords do not match';
}else { 

if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, username, password, email) VALUES 
('$name','$username', '$password','$email')")){
echo 'Successfully registered. Now try logging in.';
}else{
echo 'Oops! Please try again!';
} 

}
}
}
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

I'm not very experienced with php and its functions yet, or with stackoverflow for that matter and thus I haven't been able to figure out the solution myself yet and I can't find it online because all I'm getting is people having trouble connecting to the wifi, but I don't have that. I just want a message to get displayed if there is no internet connection available.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: How are you going to send a message from PHP on the server to your phone when there's literally no connection between the two? What you're asking for *has* to be done on the Android side. PHP has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with javascript on the client side, because the php is server side and will be executed only if is online

```html
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        context: document.body,
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('offline')
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('ONline')
        }
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got no connection, how should you be able to load the PHP page? You have to check on the client if you got an internet access, e.g. by pinging the server.

Alternatively if you're handling the sites output ('Username already exists' and so on), you could check for

```
 if(answer = "") {
 //seems to have no connection
 //your code goes here
 }
```